# Wordpress and Javascript mouseover

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mouseover

I'm trying to develop a plugin that shows website screenshot, when a user clicks on the name of the comment's author.
All works when there is just one comment, but when are more than one comment the script doesn't work.
I think the problem is in the name of the variable called and posted for each comment.
But I don't know how to dynamically change the name of the JS variable and how to dynamically call it.

This is the code for mouseover (in the header)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function MOver(picimage)
{
Picture_Over = eval(picimage +"On.src")
document[picimage].src = Picture_Over
}
function MOut(picimage)
{
Picture_Out = eval(picimage +"Off.src")
document[picimage].src = Picture_Out
}
-->
</script>
```

Then this is the code to show the mouseover:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--

var Img2On = new Image();
Img2On.src = "<?php echo $urlnohttp;?>";
var Img2Off = new Image();
Img2Off.src = "<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-content/plugins/[...]/control_play.png";

</script>
<a href="<?php echo $commenturl ?>" onMouseOver="MOver('Img2')" onMouseOut = "MOut('Img2')" ><?php echo $author ?> <img src="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-content/plugins/[...]/control_play.png" border="0" name="Img2"></img></a>
```

I think the problem is in the "Img2" name that isn't unique.

Comment: Why are you passing text, and evaling it to a variable.  You can pass the variable `onMouseOver="MOver( Img2On.src )"`, and then you can make it just one function `function MouseChange( picImage ) { document['Img2'].src = picImage; }` AND don't close your image like that.  Change it from `<img ...></img>` to `<img ... />`.  It should all be done in one tag.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i don't understand, can you explain? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am moving most of my comment over to this answer:

To dynamically call a variable, change the function to look like this:

```
function MouseChange( img , imageSrc ) // img will be the tag name, and imageSrc will be the URL of the image
{
    document[img].src = imageSrc;
}
```

To call this you will do this:

```
<?php $blogPostID = ???;// I don't know how to get blog post ID of the top of my head ?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var Img<?= $blogPostID ?>On = new Image();
    Img<?= $blogPostID ?>On.src = "<?php echo $urlnohttp;?>";
    var Img<?= $blogPostID ?>Off = new Image();
    Img<?= $blogPostID ?>Off.src = "<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-content/plugins/[...]/control_play.png";
// this closes the HTML comment: --></script>

<a href="<?php echo $commenturl ?>" onMouseOver="MouseChange( 'Img<?= $blogPostID ?>' , Img<?= $blogPostID ?>On.src )" onMouseOut = "MouseChange( 'Img<?= $blogPostID ?>' , Img<?= $blogPostID ?>Off.src )" ><?php echo $author ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-content/plugins/[...]/control_play.png" border="0" name="Img<?= $blogPostID ?>" />
</a>
```

So what I did was replace all the numbers with the blog post ID,  then you can be [relatively] sure it is unique, as long as no other parts of the page makes things called "Img#".

Comment: Javascript can't ignore the variable.  If that is what is happening, then maybe you aren't getting the Blog Post ID correctly, can you say how you are initializing it? Slash what happens when you `echo $blogPostID;`?  Does it have a value?

Comment: This is the paste bin code, http://pastebin.com/j2YZS2BU now js accept variable but doesnt do the overlay, maybe the problem is that imgsrc is dinamically generated?

Comment: Ok dude, check this out, you are using `<?php echo $urlnohttp;?>` for all the numbers (which would be outputting a path and not anything a variable can use).  You need to replace that with `<?php the_ID(); ?>`.  I changed your code to include that http://pastebin.com/3RzKHLRT